# How to convert a local date to GMT

Tags: java, date

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
java.util.Date fromDate = cal.getTime();
System.out.println(fromDate);
```

The above code doesn't print the date in GMT, but rather prints in the local timezone. How do I get a GMT equivalent date from the current date (assuming that the program can run in Japan or SFO)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

How about this -

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Test test=new Test();
    Date fromDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    System.out.println("UTC Time - "+fromDate);
    System.out.println("GMT Time - "+test.cvtToGmt(fromDate));
}
private  Date cvtToGmt( Date date ){
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
    Date ret = new Date( date.getTime() - tz.getRawOffset() );

    // if we are now in DST, back off by the delta.  Note that we are checking the GMT date, this is the KEY.
    if ( tz.inDaylightTime( ret )){
        Date dstDate = new Date( ret.getTime() - tz.getDSTSavings() );

        // check to make sure we have not crossed back into standard time
        // this happens when we are on the cusp of DST (7pm the day before the change for PDT)
        if ( tz.inDaylightTime( dstDate )){
            ret = dstDate;
        }
     }
     return ret;
}
```

**Test Result** :
UTC Time - Tue May 15 16:24:14 IST 2012
GMT Time - Tue May 15 10:54:14 IST 2012

Answer (score 18):

```
DateFormat gmtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
TimeZone gmtTime = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
gmtFormat.setTimeZone(gmtTime);
System.out.println("Current DateTime in GMT : " + gmtFormat.format(new Date()));
```

More generally you can convert to any (valid) time zone this way

---

**See**

- [`DateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html)

Comment: gmtFormat.format(new Date()) return type is String.but i want to date.

Comment: You can `parse()` that String to create Date instance

Comment: As soon as you parse, it makes it back to your local timezone format. In my case, it converts it back to IST. How to keep it in GMT

Answer (score 2):

Like this `SimpleDateFormat dateFormatGmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");
dateFormatGmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));` ?