# mssql 2005 datetime and jdbc

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, datetime, jdbc

How can I insert datetime in MS SQL 2005 with JDBC? I using stored procedures to insert in DB:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[sp_insertid_report]
@stream_time_gmt as datetime,
@stream_time_local as datetime,
@start_time_gmt as datetime,
@end_time_gmt as datetime,
@start_time_local as datetime,
@end_time_local as datetime,
@note_id as int,
@reported_by as varchar(100),
@date_reported as datetime,
@date_created as datetime,
@date_updated as datetime,
@stream_id as int,
@Fp_file_path as varchar(300),
@Fp_name as varchar(200), 
@Is_Allowed as varchar(2)

as

begin  
insert into id_reports(stream_time_gmt,stream_time_local,start_time_gmt,end_time_gmt,start_time_local,end_time_local,
note_id,reported_by,date_reported,date_created,date_updated,stream_id,Fp_file_path,Fp_name,Is_Allowed)
values(@stream_time_gmt,@stream_time_local,@start_time_gmt,@end_time_gmt,@start_time_local,
@end_time_local,@note_id,@reported_by,@date_reported,@date_created,@date_updated,@stream_id,@Fp_file_path,@Fp_name,@Is_Allowed)
end
```

And my JDBC code is:

```
    callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{ call dbo.sp_insertid_report(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) }");
        callableStatement.setDate(1, new Date(cvtToGmt(new java.util.Date(modifiedTime.toMillis())).getTime()));
        callableStatement.setDate(2, new Date(modifiedTime.toMillis()));
        callableStatement.setDate(3, new Date(cvtToGmt(startTime).getTime()));
        callableStatement.setDate(4, new Date(cvtToGmt(endTime).getTime()));
        callableStatement.setDate(5, new Date(endTime.getTime()));
        callableStatement.setDate(6, new Date(endTime.getTime()));
        callableStatement.setInt(7, songID);
        callableStatement.setString(8, AudioMatcherService.hostName);
        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
        callableStatement.setDate(9, new Date(date.getTime()));
        callableStatement.setDate(10, new Date(date.getTime()));
        callableStatement.setDate(11, new Date(date.getTime()));
        callableStatement.setInt(12, channel.getAssignmentID());
        callableStatement.setString(13, "no");
        callableStatement.setString(14, "no");
        callableStatement.setString(15, "Y");
        callableStatement.execute();
```

But this is not inserting hour, minute, second, milliseconds in DB? How can I insert this information from JDBC? Thanks in advance. I find it very hard to understand date and time things.. so many variations everywhere..

**EDIT**

Table structure is:

[image]

**EDIT**

Method cvtToGmt() is from [How to convert a local date to GMT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599109/how-to-convert-a-local-date-to-gmt/10599247#10599247)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT2**

Use `callableStatement.setTimestamp()` - this will treat as a Timestamp. `javax.sql.Timestamp` extends `java.util.Date` so you don't need to convert.

**Previous**

Maybe the `cvtToGmt()` function cuts the fractions.

Probably you have the wrong column type in your table, that does not store only the `Date`.

`Date` column type: `YYYY-MM-DD` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/bb630352.aspx

`Datetime` column type: `YYYY-MM-DD hh.mm.ss.nnn` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/ms187819.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `java.sql.Timestamp` not `java.sql.Date`

`java.util.Date` is only for "real" date columns and will remove the time part. If you need to store date *and* time you have to use `java.sql.Timestamp`.

[From the Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html):

> *To conform with the definition of SQL DATE, the millisecond values wrapped by a java.sql.Date instance must be 'normalized' by setting the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero in the particular time zone with which the instance is associated.*

And of course you will need to use `setTimestamp()` instead of `setDate()` as well.