# Milliseconds to Date in GMT in Java

Tags: java, android, date

I need to covert milliseconds to GMT date (in Android app), example:

`1372916493000`

When I convert it by this code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
cal.setTimeInMillis(millis);
Date date = cal.getTime();
```

the result is `07:41 07/04/2013`. The result is the same when I use just:

```
Date date = new Date(millis);
```

Unfortunately the result looks incorrect, it looks like my local time. I tried to convert the same number by [this service](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/java/date2millis.htm) and the result is `05:41 07/04/2013`, which I believe is correct. So I have two hours difference. Anybody has any suggestion / tips what's wrong with my conversion?

Comment: So, to be clear, you want the timestamp printed as a string using the GMT timezone?

Comment: Try to look in this answer: [How to convert a local date to GMT][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599109/how-to-convert-a-local-date-to-gmt

Comment: Did you take daylight saving time into consideration?

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230126/how-to-handle-calendar-timezones-using-java

Comment: Is the milliseconds you provided represents the time in your home timezone or GMT timezone?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If result which looks incorrect means `System.out.println(date)` then it's no surprise, because `Date.toString` converts date into string representation in local timezone. To see result in GMT you can use this

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:ss MM/dd/yyyy");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
String result = df.format(millis);
```

Comment: This code not working for me..Showing IlligalArgumentException

Answer (score 2):

It seemed you were messed up with your home timezone and the UTC timezone during the conversion.

Let's **assume you are in London** (currently London has 1 hour ahead of GMT) and the **milliseconds is the time in your home timezone** (in this case, London).

Then, you probably should:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
// Via this, you're setting the timezone for the time you're planning to do the conversion
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
cal.setTimeInMillis(1372916493000L);
// The date is in your home timezone (London, in this case)
Date date = cal.getTime();


TimeZone destTz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
// Best practice is to set Locale in case of messing up the date display
SimpleDateFormat destFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US);
destFormat.setTimeZone(destTz);
// Then we do the conversion to convert the date you provided in milliseconds to the GMT timezone
String convertResult = destFormat.parse(date);
```

Please let me know if I correctly get your point?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_372_916_493_000L )         // Moment on timeline in UTC.
```

> 2013-07-04T05:41:33Z

…and…

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_372_916_493_000L )          // Moment on timeline in UTC.
       .atZone( ZoneId.of( "Europe/Berlin" ) )  // Same moment, different wall-clock time, as used by people in this region of Germany.
```

> 2013-07-04T07:41:33+02:00[Europe/Berlin]

## Details

You are using troublesome old date-time classes now supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

## *java.time*

If you have a count of milliseconds since the epoch reference date of first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z, then parse as an `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_372_916_493_000L ) ;
```

> instant.toString(): 2013-07-04T05:41:33Z

To see that same simultaneous moment through the lens of a particular region’s wall-clock time, apply a time zone (`ZoneId`) to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Berlin" ) ; 
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2013-07-04T07:41:33+02:00[Europe/Berlin]

---

## About *java.time*

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Test test=new Test();
        Date fromDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        System.out.println("UTC Time - "+fromDate);
        System.out.println("GMT Time - "+test.cvtToGmt(fromDate));
    }
    private  Date cvtToGmt( Date date )
        {
           TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
           Date ret = new Date( date.getTime() - tz.getRawOffset() );

           // if we are now in DST, back off by the delta.  Note that we are checking the GMT date, this is the KEY.
           if ( tz.inDaylightTime( ret ))
           {
              Date dstDate = new Date( ret.getTime() - tz.getDSTSavings() );

              // check to make sure we have not crossed back into standard time
              // this happens when we are on the cusp of DST (7pm the day before the change for PDT)
              if ( tz.inDaylightTime( dstDate ))
              {
                 ret = dstDate;
              }
           }

           return ret;
        }
}
```

**Test Result** :
UTC Time - Tue May 15 16:24:14 IST 2012
GMT Time - Tue May 15 10:54:14 IST 2012

Answer (score 0):

`Date date = cal.getTime();`

returns date created via

```
public final Date getTime() {
    return new Date(getTimeInMillis());
}
```

where `getTimeInMillis()` returns milliseconds without any TimeZone.

I would suggest looking here for how to do what you want [how-to-handle-calendar-timezones-using-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230126/how-to-handle-calendar-timezones-using-java)

Comment: But is the time in milliseconds be generated based on GMT or the time zone in which the device/desktop is present?