# Wrong conversion of time stamp to date android

Tags: android

I'm trying to convert this time stamp value to date but its giving me wrong time. date is correct

```
TimeStamp : 1423821615
True Value : Fri, 13 Feb 2015 10:00:15 GMT
Android Code shows : Fri, 13 Feb 2015 15:30:15 IST
```

Here is the code I'm using to convert time stamp to date.

```
Date dt = new Date((long)timestampInSeconds * 1000);
```

I tried this code too but same result

```
public static Date getDateFromTimeStamp(long timestampInMilliseconds) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(timestampInMilliseconds);
    return cal.getTime();
}

Date dt = getDateFromTimeStamp((long)timestampInSeconds * 1000);
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please help

---

Now I explain the whole scenario. My client is from UK and I'm from India (+5:30 ahead). He created appointment for 10 AM in UK obviously. But now I have his database in my local PC. My .NET software it shows same time as it shows in below image of SQL server. But in mobile, it doesn't. PC and mobile both are in same time zone.

[image]

I use this code to convert date to time stamp and send this time stamp to mobile app through web service

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND,{d '1970-01-01'}, Appointments.DateTime) AS AppointmentTimeStamp FROM Appointments
```

Here is image of what my .NET software displays
[image]

does it matter that record was created when database was in UK time zone. Or I'm still doing a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Check your value, since you have 30minutes of difference, this is not a timezone problem.

Comment: Its not 30 mins of difference. its 5 hours and 30 mins

Comment: @AxelH [O'RLY](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/time-zones-interesting.html)

Comment: @Selvin, well, that I didn't knew ^^ `India: UTC +5:30`

Comment: @AxelH, I already provided the time stamp value. "1423821615"

Comment: since India is +5:30 it's probably a timezone problem. You are probably stamping the timestamp of India and retrieving the time of GMT, might it be?

Comment: @Krishna, are you from India or Sri Lanka ? This seems to match with this timezone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Milliseconds to Date in GMT in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472989/milliseconds-to-date-in-gmt-in-java)

Comment: @AxelH yes, I have .net software which shows correct time and in mobile its not. my PC and mobile both have same time zone

Comment: @Selvin I can't believe this is the first time I heard about this ... thanks for the info, well for the link without any information ;)

Comment: let me try what @PierGiorgioMisley suggested

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what you wanna get.
If you get time as EPOCH time, you don't have information about time zone where this time stamp was made. So, you should know time zone offset and + or minus this seconds from this time stamp.

But I think the best way to use ISO 8601 format for time stamp, it's easy to convert to any timezone what you need

for example, this code convert ISO data to local time or return current time depends on locale timezone

```
private long time2LocalTimeZone (String date){

        //"2016-07-29T23:07:45.120+00"
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", Locale.getDefault());

        try {

            return sdf.parse(date).getTime();

        } catch (ParseException e){

            return (new Date()).getTime();

        }
    }
```

this code count your offset from GMT timezone and convert to epoch time depends on locale timezone

```
private long time2LocalTimeZone (long date){
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
        Date now = new Date();
        int offsetFromUtc = tz.getOffset(now.getTime()) / 1000;
        return date + offsetFromUtc;
    }
```

Comment: I need to display same date with time which is stored in SQL server. You can see that in first image. and I want to convert timestamp to date not date to time stamp.

Comment: Right now i have only one way to display what i need to is to send date in string format through web service

Comment: Ok, ISO string like this yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ contain all necessary info and database can give you date in ISO format. Or If you have all rows in DB with GMT time zone time stamp you should minus 330 sec from this time bucause android think that it's Epoch time in locale timezone

Comment: I've added more example, but it's only good way if your records in DB  have constant time stamp in GMT or any other timezone